# How to find out what list item in a mongo full text search was matched?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection containing the names of clients and a list of books they each have read.   I added a full-text index on the title of the books

```
clients.ensure_index([("books.title",pymongo.TEXT)])
```

Some clients read one book, some read 100.

Here's where I got stuck:

I need to know exactly which book title was matched by the full text search.  For example, if I search for "olive", like so..

```
clients.find({"$text": {"$search": "olive"}})
```

This returns to me the full document for each match, but it doesn't tell me which book title was matched.

My first thought was to iterate thru the search results and find the exact match myself, but then I realized that Mongo does all kind of stemming and other query normalization techniques.

This means that "olive" will match "olives" ..etc

This means that even if I iterate over the results of the full-text query and try to locate the matching book title myself, I might not find it!   Due to the query normalization.

So, how can I find out what book title was matched?

Is this a limitation of Mongo?

Comment: Hi @rf987, AFAIK you can use the query planner to determine what search term is used. `clients.find({"$text": {"$search": "olive"}})` returns a cursor on which you can call the `explain` method to view the query plan. e.g. For `olive`, the search term is `oliv`.

Comment: Hi @OluwafemiSule, thanks, this is a start.  This gives me the stemmed search term, but I still need to stem all the book names manually so I can find a match, and I need to make sure I use the exact same stemming algo.